# UWP BitmapImage Blank after ScreenSaver

Tags: c#, uwp, bitmapimage

Working on a UWP application that has several images (background images, images as buttons, etc). We have a requirement that the Windows screen saver kicks off after x minutes of inactivity. The issue is that when the screen saver is interrupted and the application continues, the images (as BitmapImages) are blank. If you navigate around the app a little...the images eventually reload.

Is there a way to force them to reload (I already have a DispatcherTimer mechanism in place to reset the app to its default state when the screen saver kicks in)?

Comment: The same problem occurs on phones when you switch to another app and your app is in a background for a long time.